# ActiveRecord Query for Child, Sort by Grandparent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm seeing tons of examples of using attributes on a parent element for sorting, but nothing for grandparent. If there's another post out there detailing this, I couldn't find it, maybe because I don't know the word for it. So, here are my theoretical models:

```
class GrandParent < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :parents
    has_many :children, through: :parents
end


class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :grand_parent
    has_many   :children
end


class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :parent
end
```

So, I'm trying to present a list of children, but I want it sorted by grandparents.

I was trying useless things like `Child.joins(:grandparent).order('grandparent.name').all`

But that's just not doing it for me. I've attempted a hundred other variants, but I can't say they had much logic behind them... 
Anyone have any good thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
Child.joins(:parent => :grand_parent).order('grand_parents.name')
```

Comment: This feels more like what I was looking for. Thank you! It also works a lot faster than iterating over all of them. About 1 second (this method) vs 17 seconds (iterating) for 6000 objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not concerned about speed, you could use a much more explicit way to sort these objects that is easy to understand. In particular,

```
children.sort_by{|child| child.grand_parent.name}
```

It's not using full SQL and won't be great if you have lots of `children`, but sometimes it's worth optimizing for ease of implementation.

Comment: I just checked, and that works just fine for some instances. I do in this database have about 7000 "grandchildren" though. I would love to see a solution that is a bit more database/activerecord oriented if at all possible. Using a query that returns about 6000 results, it takes about 20 seconds. That's eerily long, as it's close to Heroku's timeout limit. The only faster solution that I can think of would be to copy grandparent names to either parents or children. But having duplication in the database like that, just feels wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Best to stay away from using array (enumerable) sorts when working with active record if possible!